# Jquery Ajax on high value string, Method is not calling

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

For small string data method is being called, But for high string data method not allowed exception or sometime request entity too large error is coming.

Here is my code:

```
$("#Exceldownload_jobAlloctn").click(function(){
    var getrowdata = $('#location_grid_for_hub').jqxGrid('getrows');
    var getrowdata = JSON.stringify(getrowdata);

    if($('#location_grid_for_hub').jqxGrid('getrows').length == 0)
                {
                    callnotify_alert("Error","No Data to Export",'danger');
                    return false;
                }
    else{
   
    //json.stringfy();
  //  console.log(tickets_jqxgrid_rows);
        $.ajax({
            headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            url: "/Exportdata",
            dataType: 'text',
            type: "POST",
           // cache:false,
           processData: true,
        //    contentType: true,
            data: {"grid_data":getrowdata },
            error: function (error) {

                   console.log(error);
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                
               // excel_nm= data;
                var excel_nm= data;
                var link1 = document.createElement("a");
                document.body.appendChild(link1);
                link1.download = data;
                link1.title = data;
                link1.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                link1.setAttribute("download", data);
                 var url=$("#excelfile_url").val();
                link1.href = url+excel_nm; 
                
                link1.click();
                document.body.removeChild(link1);
                }

        });
    }
    
    });
```

Even tried increasing memory limit and post max size, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to SO,

If you are using httpd, you can try and set

```
LimitRequestBody 0
```

to your httpd.conf ( and maybe .htaccess ). That should set unlimited length for request body.
See: [Apache HTTP Server Docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody)

If you are running nginx, then you need to set

```
client_max_body_size {SIZE}M;
```

for example

```
client_max_body_size 512M;
```

[See NGINX Docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size)

Don't forget to restart httpd/nginx.